# Find closest match in a column using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering how I can find the closest value that matches a certain number from a table.
What I currently have is:

```
$result = DB::table('numbers')
            ->orderBy('s/me - $input', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

**s/me** being the column name I want to find the match. But it keeps giving me an `Interface 'Throwable' not found` error.

Comment: Why do  you append ` - $input` to column name?

Comment: Can you add the error message ? What do you mean by _closest value that match a certain number from a table_ ?

Comment: @MichaelChen I was trying to subtract the values from that column with the value in $input, then sort the results from the highest difference to the lowest. I thought it would work that way. I tried 's/me' - $input also won't work.

Comment: @Cedias the error is *Interface 'Throwable' not found*. What I'm trying to do is I have a column named s/me and I want to find the value on that column which is the closest to the one on $input.

Comment: Can you exemplify ? What keeps you from simply using  a `->where()` clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$result = DB::table('numbers')
            ->select('*', DB::raw('ABS(s/me - :input) AS distance'))
            ->setBindings(['input' => $input])  
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->get();
```

Credits to source [here](http://www.techfounder.net/2009/02/02/selecting-closest-values-in-mysql/).

Comment: can u provide the whole file code? the cause could be from the a diff source. are you using try/catch block?

Comment: `function calc(Request $request){
        $input = $request->input;
        $result = DB::table('numbers')
            ->select('sme', DB::raw('ABS(sme - $input) AS distance'))  
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->get();
        dd($result);
}`

And no, I'm not using try/catch

Comment: ahh you should enclosed string on `DB::raw` with double quotes or concat (using dot) it  since `$input` is a variable.

Comment: Tried `->select('sme', DB::raw("ABS(sme - $input) AS distance")) ` and `->select('sme', DB::raw('ABS(sme -'.$input.') AS distance')) ` still getting the same error message. Odd.

Comment: ahh, is your `POST/GET` variable named `input`? if so, use this instead `$input = $request->input('input');`

Comment: Actually it now worked when you told me to concat it. Stupid me was trying to query on the wrong table! It seems to be pulling up the results I want properly now. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: ahaha i see. no probs!

Comment: I edited this answer to protect the code from SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You can't do operation directly in orderBy,

Try this:

```
$result = DB::table('numbers')
    ->select('*', DB::raw("(s/me - $input) AS column_to_be_order"))
    ->orderBy('column_to_be_order', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Still somehow giving me the same error. Even replacing $input with a fixed number won't work.